# Location service onProviderEnabled never called

Tags: android, service, location

I have a service to update location in my app. When I start my app with GPS disable, go back to android menu and enable GPS, and finally go back to my app (the service has not been destroyed), onProviderEnabled is never called. Anybody could help?

**UPDATE:** if I restarts the app the provider is enabled. Only onProviderEnabled is not called...

In every activity in which I need location I do

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    //....

    // Bind location service
    bindService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    //....
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();       
    // Unbind LocationService
    ItemDetail.this.unbindService(mConnection);
}
```

and the service is

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener {
    LocationManager locationManager; 

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {        
        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){         

            // Update after minimum 5 minutes and if user has moved at least 100 meters.
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5 * 60 * 1000, 100, this);        

            Location loc = getBestLocation(locationManager);
            if(loc!=null){
                GlobalVars.lat = (Double) (loc.getLatitude());
                GlobalVars.lng = (Double) (loc.getLongitude());
            }
        }
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {        
        GlobalVars.lat = (Double) (loc.getLatitude());
        GlobalVars.lng = (Double) (loc.getLongitude()); 
    }

    public static Location getBestLocation(LocationManager locationManager) {

        Location location_gps = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Location location_network = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        // If both are available, get the most recent
        if(location_gps!=null && location_network !=null) {
            return (location_gps.getTime() > location_network.getTime())?location_gps:location_network;
        }
        else if(location_gps==null && location_network ==null){
            return null;
        }
        else
            return (location_gps==null)?location_network:location_gps;

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String s){
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5 * 60 * 1000, 100, this); 
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        GlobalVars.lat = null;
        GlobalVars.lng = null;  
    }
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b){}

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {       
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hei! Did you manage the problem? I'm looking to do something like you do,too - so I would be glad to use your code as reference material.
I'm Still confused how to use a service with location manager to come around running into ANRs...

Answer (score 2):

In your `LocationService.onCreate()` method your code checks if the GPS provider is disabled.

```
if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){...}
```

But you only start the subscription if it is already enabled. Note that your listener is then never registered with the `LocationManager` and will not receive any updates of location providers being disabled or enabled. Rather change your `onCreate()` method to always call

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5 * 60 * 1000, 100, this);
```