# Why isn't Android's onProviderEnabled() method being called?

Tags: android, locationmanager

My Android app has two location listeners, one for fine and one for coarse listening.  I want to be able to detect when the user turns their location services off and on.

Whenever I turn my phones GPS or network location services OFF the onProviderDisabled method is called as expected.  When I turn GPS or network services ON the onProviderEnabled is never called!

I have put the code for one of the listeners below....

***Update...***

I have discovered that the problem is related to unregistering the listeners in onPause.  When I remove the code ***"locationManager.removeUpdates(myFineLocationListener);"***  the onProviderEnabled() method IS called.

Perhaps the act of disabling the (say) GPS automatically unregisters the listener?  Perhaps I should unregister thje listener in onDestroy rather than onPause() ???

PS.  Maybe it is relevant that I mention that my activity has a button that goes directly to the devices location settings page. It acts as a shortcut.  I use this shortcut to disable/enable location services then use the Back button to return to my app.  I will put the code for this button at the very end of this post.

***Code:***

(The createLocListeners() method is called from onCreate();)

```
 void createLocListeners() {

        //if null, create a new listener
        //myFineLocationListener is a class variable     
        if (myFineLocationListener == null) {

        //Listen for FINE location updates   
                myFineLocationListener = new LocationListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        //Do something
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {   
                                 //This gets called when I change location settings (eg GPS on or off)  on the phone            }



                                  @Override
                           public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                                  //This DOES NOT get called when I change location settings (eg GPS on or off)  on the phone   
                           }

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {   
                    }

                };  //end on location listener
        } //end if fine listener is null

    } //end createLocListener() function






    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //REGISTER LOCATION LISTENERS
        try {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LISTENING_INTERVAL, LISTENING_DISTANCE, myFineLocationListener);
        } 
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
        //Tried catching exceptions but there weren't any
        }         
        catch (RuntimeException e) {            
        }





    }// end onResume()




    @Override     
        protected void onPause() {         
        super.onPause();        

        //UNREGISTER LOCATION LISTENERS
        locationManager.removeUpdates(myFineLocationListener);

    } //end onPause
```

**Similar problem:** [Location service onProviderEnabled never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454990/location-service-onproviderenabled-never-called)

***Code for button that opens the location Settings page...***

```
        //JUMP TO LOCATION SERVICES SETTINGS
    ibLoc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
        }

    }); //end jump to location services button listener
```

Comment: where are you calling createLocListeners()?

Comment: It is being called from oncreate()

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IMO, when you go to settings the `onPause()` is called and listeners are unregistered. Then you enable the GPS and return to your activity. So when you register the listeners the GPS is already enabled, so listener `onProviderEnabled()` is never called, since it is only called when GPS status is *changed* to enabled.

Comment: This makes sense to me except why would onProviderDisabled() still be called?

Comment: Hm, thats curious. Does this happen if you disable GPS and then wait a minute before returning to app?

Comment: Yes it does, which (as the listeners are unregister in onPause()), I suppose is actually weirder than onProviderEnabled() not being called!  From what I have read the generally accepted place to register location listeners is onResume() and unregister in onPause.  The more I think about this problem, onResume and onPause seem like inappropriate places...

Comment: I think I figured it out. In my code leaving the activity calls onPause() and unregisters the listener.  The location service is either enabled or disabled by user.  Returning to the activity calls onResume() and registers listeners again by calling requestLocationUpdates().  However, from documentation,  if requestLocationUpdates is called from an already disabled provider, onProviderDisabled is called immediately.  (In contrast onProviderEnabled() is not called immediately.)  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html

Comment: Ahh, great find. Got to remember this one.

Answer (score 1):

I had `mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this)` in `onStop()` which was getting called when I pulled down the Notification Tray to turn on the locations services. So though I turn on the locations, my `onProviderEnabled()` was not getting called. Thanks for the hint @Peter.