# Android: Google Map provider is disabled

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, location, google-maps-api-2

I am implementing Location Listener in Google Map for getting updating current location by using the override function **`onLocationChanged()`**;

Manifest

```
<permission
    android:name="com.ccs.navigation.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.ccs.navigation.permission.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Calling the `onLocationChangeListener` by

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 1, this);
```

But when i try to run the code it automatically calls `onProviderDisabled()` override function

**build.gradle**

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'`

I am not getting why its going `onProviderDisabled`

Can any one please help me.

Comment: Make sure that you enable location permissions

Comment: in setting Location is ON @LvN

Comment: onProviderDisabled(String provider) Called when the provider is disabled by the user.

Comment: Have you used `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`? Check this SO question [15142089](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15142091/5995040) for the setMyLocationEnabled(true) and [7508173](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7590250/5995040) to know better about the behavior of `onProviderDisabled`. Hope this helps!